# Accessing a Web API site in Azure protected by ACS from a Metro App

Tags: c#, azure, windows-8, acs

I have an Azure Worker role running a ASP.Net Web API application. This is protected by ACS. When I browse to the web api using a browser, I get challenged by ACS to authenticate against either Google or LiveId. When I authenticate, I can see the data.

I am trying to access the same API from a Win 8 Metro Style App. I am trying to use the WebAuthenticationBroker.

```c#
WebAuthenticationResult webAuthenticationResult = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(
                                                        WebAuthenticationOptions.None,
                                                        new Uri("https://xxxxx.accesscontrol.windows.net:443/v2/wsfederation?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=http%3a%2f%2fyyyyy.cloudapp.net%2f"),
                                                        new Uri("http://yyyyy.cloudapp.net/")
                                                       );
```

When I start the app, it challenges me to Authenticate either through Google or LiveId as before. This passes and I get a successful result.

Then I create a call to the API using a HttpClient:

```c#
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    Uri _baseUri = new Uri("http://yyyyy.cloudapp.net/api/");
    client.BaseAddress = _baseUri;

    var response = client.GetAsync("Values/").Result;
    var responseBodyAsText = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

    var ids = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<int>>(responseBodyAsText);
```

This sort of works, it appears to be navigating to the URI correctly, but the payload that come back is HTML asking me to log in rather than the JSON data I am expecting.

I have spent more time on this than is sensible and have run out of ideas! Can anyone please help?

Comment: I have the same issues. Depending on what login provider used, the responsedata are different. Using facebook, the result are a long string like : /v2/facebook?cx=cHI9d3NmZWRlcmF0aW9uJnJtPWh0 and using LiveID its short: net/v2/wsfederation?wa=wsignin1.0. I also would love to know how to go on from here

Comment: So far i have found out that, the url for facebook needs response_type=token to get the token. Assuming something like that for the other providers also

Comment: response_type=code for google

Comment: Here is a working solution.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12485665/does-the-webauthenticationbroker-work-in-windows-8-metro-app-post-release-candid

Comment: My next issue is, that now i have changed the return url on ACS to the controller that redirects such it work for the metro app. But then my web interface dont work as it excepts the return url to be http://yyyyy.cloudapp.net/

Answer (score 2):

You have to make sure when testing on localhost that ACS can access your computer.

And as @caleb wrote, you need to listen for the token and redirect it for the broker. 
You can see my post with a working example and how to set it up.

[Does the WebAuthenticationBroker work in Windows 8 Metro App post Release Candidate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12485665/does-the-webauthenticationbroker-work-in-windows-8-metro-app-post-release-candid)

Answer (score 1):

The `WebAuthenticationBroker` will simply keep browsing until the url the browser is going to load is the one specified in the callbackUri parameter.  It will then return the final url to you, including any query parameters.  It never actually makes the request to the callbackUri.

The problem you are having is that the WS-Federation protocol which ACS implements posts the token back to return url (specified in the ACS config portal), which is probably the same url you have specified as the callbackUri parameter in your AuthenticateAsync method.

What you need to do is handle that post and redirect the request to the callbackUri, but with the query string including the token.

I'm using WebApi and WIF and I have my callbackUri specified as `http://localhost:3949/api/federationcallback/end` and return url specified as `http://localhost:3949/api/federationcallback`. This allows me to have a controller handle the post and then redirect with the token in the URL.  The controller looks like this.

```
public class FederationcallbackController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Post()
    {
        var response = this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Redirect);
        response.Headers.Add("Location", "/api/federationcallback/end?acsToken=" + ExtractBootstrapToken());

        return response;
    }

    protected virtual string ExtractBootstrapToken()
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.User.BootstrapToken();
    }
}
```

I can then get the token like this:

```
var authenticateResult = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(
            WebAuthenticationOptions.None,
            new Uri("https://xyz.accesscontrol.windows.net:443/v2/wsfederation?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost:3949%2f"),
            new Uri("http://localhost:3949/api/federationcallback/end"));

var oauthToken = authenticateResult.ResponseData.Substring(authenticateResult.ResponseData.IndexOf("acsToken=", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 9);
```

Comment: what is the bootstraptoken method?

Comment: and does the ACS know that localhost is my ip and not localhost as the localhost of the ACS ?

Comment: The BootstrapToken method is an extension method included in the wif.swt NuGet package.  I thought it was a part of WIF which is why I didn't mention it before.

Comment: ACS just tells the browser to redirect to localhost and the browser then resolves the name.  ACS doesn't talk to it directly.

Comment: @CalebVear, I'm just trying to run through your example with ACS and WebApi running locally, without adding in the client and the WebAuthenticationBroker yet. I have my ACS relying party's Return Uri = localhost:25807/api/auth, and I have code similar to your FederationcallbackController there to handle the post, but that controller never seems to get called. I'm debugging. I have a breakpoint in the post method, and fiddler running, and ACS is not posting my token to that URL. My browser never gets redirected to my Return Uri. Any idea why?

Comment: @AndrewBSchultz sorry, I can't think of anything at the moment other than to double check your ACS configuration.  Also make sure you specify a callback URI that is different to the one you are posting to as the the WebAuthenticationBroker will stop the process as soon as it sees a request for that URI.

Comment: Thanks Caleb! Hmmm...seems like I might have had it pointing at the IP address rather than local host at times - sometimes the Identity and Access Tool in VS2012 defaults to IP address (if I'm not mistaken). I wasn't paying close enough attention, but I'm guessing that was my issue. With localhost rather than 127.0.0.1 as my return uri, my return uri is finally seeing some traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you re-use the token in `WebAuthenticationResult` when calling the API?

```c#
var webAuthenticationResult = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions.None, 
        new Uri("https://xxxxx.accesscontrol.windows.net:443/v2/wsfederation?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=http%3a%2f%2fyyyyy.cloudapp.net%2f"), new Uri("http://yyyyy.cloudapp.net/"));

var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization
        = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("OAuth", webAuthenticationResult.ResponseData);
```

Comment: How do I get the token from the WebAuthenticationResponse?

Comment: From what I understand the token should be in the ResponseData property

Comment: That doesn't work - all I get back in the ResponseData is http://yyyyy.cloudapp.net/ Does it matter this is http not https?

Comment: I have found that the ResponseData does NOT contain a security token and I can't see how to get it from WebAuthenticationBroker. Did you ever get any further on this?

Comment: Sadly not, I gave up and am waiting until it matures a little or I find an answer on Google. If you do find out how it works, please let me know.