# Does the WebAuthenticationBroker work in Windows 8 Metro App post Release Candidate

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, microsoft-metro

**SOLUTION**
My working solution can be found in the answer or in my update two.

1) Now make sure, for testing on localhost, that you have setup windows firewalls for inbound on the localhost port. Port forwarding on the router if you have one.

2) Then you need to tell IIS Express that its okay that the request comes from outsite the localhost:
Find Documents\IISExpress\config and edit applicationhost.config. Find your site in the list and **remove the localhost from the binding**.

```
        <site name="S-Innovations.TrafficTheory.Web2" id="1591449597">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="G:\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\S-Innovations.TrafficTheory\S-Innovations.TrafficTheory.Web2" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:909090:localhost" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
```

2a) ISS need to run as administrator, running visual studio as administrator also starts iss as admin...

3) Locate your ip, www.myip.com and change the ACS return uri to : `http://90.90.90.90:909090/api/federation/`

4) change the webbroker to use your ip also:

```
        WebAuthenticationResult webAuthenticationResult = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(
WebAuthenticationOptions.None,
new Uri("https://traffictheory.accesscontrol.windows.net:443/v2/wsfederation?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a48451%2f"),
new Uri("http://99.99.99.99:909090/api/federation/end"));
```

Everything worked for me like this. I got a hello world passed on to my metro app as the token.

**Problem**

I have set up a WCF Service and a Metro App.
The WCF service is set up to authenticate using Azure ACS.

I made a Console Application that works with the WebService and ACS:

```
            static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {

                // First start the web project, then the client
                WebClient client = new WebClient();
                var token = RetrieveACSToken();
                client.Headers.Add("Authorization", token);
                client.Headers.Add("Content-type", "text/xml");
                var url = new Uri("http://traffictheory.azurewebsites.net/UserService.svc/Users");
                //var url = new Uri("http://localhost:4000/UserService.svc/Users");//
                Stream stream = client.OpenRead(url);
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
                String response = reader.ReadToEnd();
                Console.Write(response);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write(ex.Message);
            }
              Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static string RetrieveACSToken()
        {
            var acsHostName     = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ACSHostName");
            var acsNamespace    = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ACSNamespace");
            var username        = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ServiceIdentityUserName");
            var password        = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ServiceIdentityCredentialPassword");
            var scope = "http://traffictheory.azurewebsites.net/"; 
            //var scope = "http://localhost:4000/";// 
            // request a token from ACS
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.BaseAddress = string.Format("https://{0}.{1}", acsNamespace, acsHostName);
            NameValueCollection values = new
            NameValueCollection();
            values.Add("wrap_name", username);
            values.Add("wrap_password", password);
            values.Add("wrap_scope", scope);
            byte[] responseBytes =
            client.UploadValues("WRAPv0.9", "POST", values);
            string response =
            Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes);
            string token = response
            .Split('&')
            .Single(value =>
            value.StartsWith("wrap_access_token=",
            StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            .Split('=')[1];
            var decodedToken = string.Format("WRAP access_token=\"{0}\"", HttpUtility.UrlDecode(token));
            return decodedToken;
        }
```

I face two problems now when i want to use it from my Metro App.
First one is unrelated to the service and is about the WebAuthenticationBroker.

1)
 When i use

```
WebAuthenticationResult webAuthenticationResult = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(
                WebAuthenticationOptions.None,
                new Uri("https://s-innovations.accesscontrol.windows.net:443/v2/wsfederation?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=http%3a%2f%2ftraffictheory.azurewebsites.net%2f"),
                new Uri("https://s-innovations.accesscontrol.windows.net")
            );
```

I am able to log in using, LiveID, Facebook ect. Not google because ACS dont include the ID correctly. But I dont get any kind of token back or Claims. I only get:

https://s-innovations.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/wsfederation?wa=wsignin1.0
https://s-innovations.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/facebook?cx=cHI9d3NmZWRlcmF0aW9uJn...cmFmZmljdGhlb3J5LmF6dXJld2Vic2l0ZXMubmV0JTJmJmlwPUZhY2Vib29rLTM1NTk5MjQ2NzgxNzc5OQ2&code=AQDagvqoXQ.......

How do I get the claims like in the end of this movie: 
http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/SAC-858T
His app works!

2)
The console app shown above get authenticated and get the token to pass to the service when calling the API, how do i get this token from within the metro app.

**UPDATE**

I created the controller as suggested:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult End()
{
    return Json("Hello World");
}
```

I have put in a break point to see if it get it. No hit yet.

```
    WebAuthenticationResult webAuthenticationResult = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(
WebAuthenticationOptions.None,
new Uri("https://traffictheory.accesscontrol.windows.net:443/v2/wsfederation?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a48451%2f"),
new Uri("http://localhost:909090/Federation/End"));
```

On my Relying Party Application i ahave

```
Realm http://localhost:909090/
Return Url: Nothing  (have tried http://localhost:909090/Federation/End )
```

The response data contains : `http://localhost:909090/Federation/End` right now.

**UPDATE 2**

I also tried with an api controller as you shown in another post:

public class FederationController : ApiController
{

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post()
{
    var response = this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Redirect);
    response.Headers.Add("Location", "/api/federation/end?acsToken=" + ExtractBootstrapToken());

    return response;
}
public string Get()
{
    return "hello world";
}
protected virtual string ExtractBootstrapToken()
{
    return "Hello World";
}
```

}

Now the login screen just hang and ends with a service you looking for is not ready right now (or something like that).

acs return url `http://localhost:48451/api/Federation`

```
        WebAuthenticationResult webAuthenticationResult = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(
WebAuthenticationOptions.None,
new Uri("https://traffictheory.accesscontrol.windows.net:443/v2/wsfederation?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a909090%2f"),
new Uri("http://localhost:909090/api/federation/end"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `WebAuthenticationBroker` simply keeps browsing until the next requested page is the one specified by the `callbackUri` parameter.  At that point it returns the final URL to you so if you want to get anything back it needs to be encoded in that URL.

In the ACS control panel for the relying party you need to specify a return url that is somewhere on your site.  For example `https://traffictheory.azurewebsites.net/federationcallback`.  Then create a controller to handle accept a post to that URL.  The post will have a form field `wresult` which is some xml that will contain the token returned from ACS.

You can then send the token back to the `WebAuthenticationBroker` by redirecting to `https://traffictheory.azurewebsites.net/federationcallback/end?token={whatever you want to return}`

You would then need to change the usage of the authentication broker to the following:

```
var webAuthenticationResult = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(
            WebAuthenticationOptions.None,
            new Uri("https://s-innovations.accesscontrol.windows.net:443/v2/wsfederation?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=http%3a%2f%2ftraffictheory.azurewebsites.net%2f"),
            new Uri("https://traffictheory.azurewebsites.net/federationcallback/end")
        );

// The data you returned
var token = authenticateResult.ResponseData.Substring(authenticateResult.ResponseData.IndexOf("token=", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 6);
```

My controller for handling the authentication callback post looks like this.

```
public class FederationcallbackController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Post()
    {
        var response = this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Redirect);
        response.Headers.Add("Location", "/api/federationcallback/end?acsToken=" + ExtractBootstrapToken());

        return response;
    }

    protected virtual string ExtractBootstrapToken()
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.User.BootstrapToken();
    }
}
```

The `BootstrapToken()` extenion method is part of the `wif.swt` NuGet package.  By default WIF doesn't save anything to the bootstrap token property you need to enable it by including the `saveBootstrapTokens="true"` attribute on the `<service>` element under `<microsoft.identityModel>` in your web.config.  Mine looks like this:

```
<microsoft.identityModel>
    <service saveBootstrapTokens="true">
        <audienceUris>
            <add value="http://localhost:3949/" />
        </audienceUris>
        <federatedAuthentication>
            <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="true" issuer="https://xyz.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/wsfederation" realm="http://localhost:3949/" reply="http://localhost:3949/" requireHttps="false" />
            <cookieHandler requireSsl="false" path="/" />
        </federatedAuthentication>
        <issuerNameRegistry type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Swt.SwtIssuerNameRegistry, Wif.Swt">
            <trustedIssuers>
                <add name="https://readify.accesscontrol.windows.net/" thumbprint="{thumbprint}" />
            </trustedIssuers>
        </issuerNameRegistry>
        <securityTokenHandlers>
            <add type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Swt.SwtSecurityTokenHandler, Wif.Swt" />
        </securityTokenHandlers>
        <issuerTokenResolver type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Swt.SwtIssuerTokenResolver, Wif.Swt" />
    </service>
</microsoft.identityModel>
```

Comment: Do i get it right?. The ACS site sends the token to my website, i then need to store the token there until the broker asks for it?

Comment: I think i know what you mean now, i tried and have updated the question with the information. hope it makes sense

Comment: So i found the solution. You are right about this. But to test all this on localhost people have to make sure that inbound rules and the ACS can access your local machine.

Comment: I am using Microsoft.Identity and my  ((ClaimsIdentity)((ClaimsPrincipal)HttpContext.Current.User).Identity).BootstrapToken do not pass as a string. Any advise on how i should serialize the token to send.

Comment: There is an attribute you need to set in your web.config.  I've updated this answer with the details.

Comment: Im using SAML 2.0 on my ACS, does this have any impact=

Comment: I changed to SWT and did set it up as you told. On the client i did set following on my httpClient : client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", token); where token is the token returned from HttpContext.Current.User.BootstrapToken(). Sadly the webapi request ends up in  FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.AuthorizationFailed  event

Comment: Unfortunately WIF doesn't support OAuth headers out of the box.  You can implement an HttpModule to do the authentication.  I only want to use OAuth for the web api calls so I implemented an HttpMessageHandler to do it.  You can see my implementation here: https://gist.github.com/3798027

Comment: Looks like you are targeting for .net 4.5?  i get alot of compile errors for the handler. Know any for 4.0?

Comment: //request.SetUserPrincipal(principal);  Cant get this line to compile.  and adding this , does it mean that the normal authentication wont work on the api ?

Comment: Other then above comment, things start to work. Both authentications work against the api. One issue now is that the bootstrapped token do not have other claims than nameidentifier and provider. this means i cant do[Authorize(Roles="BLALABLA")]

Comment: I think SetUserPrincipal() is new to .net 4.5 which I am targeting. It doesn't matter unless you are using the corresponding GetUserPrincipal() method as most of the other features use the current thread or http context to do the auth.

Comment: You should have all of the claims that were initially posted in the bootstrap token.  If you are missing some I don't know why it would be happening as all of mine remain intact.

Comment: You are correct, the bootstrap token has all the initial claims. I was hoping to pass those along i did add myself upon succesfull authentication. (adding some roles and stuff).

Comment: In that case you will need to serialize the claims into a new token.  I imagine that you can do that with WIF, but I haven't done it so unfortunately I can't help you with it at the moment.

Comment: This question/answer are a bit hard to follow. Do you have a blog post that has it organized sequentially? Maybe with source code available?

Comment: I've gotten to a place where my controller returns hello world as the token but it appears when I actually use HttpContext.Current.User.BootstrapToken();
 it returns an empty string.

Comment: It sounds like you may not have the Swt token handlers setup correctly.  I'm sorry I can't be more helpful at the moment it has been quite awhile since I last did this and my memory is a little vague.  Unfortunately I don't have a blog post about it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Probably a silly question, does the site hosting the controller "FederationController" that uses the IPrincipal.BootstrapToken() need to have ACS authentication enabled on it?

Comment: It does need to be setup to handle tokens from ACS so you could say it does need to have ACS authentication enabled.