# Getting ACS token on windows store app using callback Uri

Tags: wcf, windows-store-apps, acs

I've been following the steps to make Windows 8 Store app get an ACS token as described here:
[Does the WebAuthenticationBroker work in Windows 8 Metro App post Release Candidate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12485665/does-the-webauthenticationbroker-work-in-windows-8-metro-app-post-release-candid)

However, the ResponseData property of my WebAuthenticationResult object only contains the callback uri as specified in ACS, and contains no token information. Below my code.

**Authentication method of Windows 8 client**

```
private async void Authenticate()
    {
        WebAuthenticationResult webAuthenticationResult = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(
            WebAuthenticationOptions.None,
            new Uri("https://myACSnamespace.accesscontrol.windows.net:443/v2/wsfederation?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=http://localhost:12714/"),
            new Uri("http://mypublicIPaddress:80/WebAppMVCAPI/api/federation/end"));
```

My *Relying Party application* Return URL is set to `http://mypublicIPaddress:80/WebAppMVCAPI/api/federation/en`

My controller on the web application is programmed as follows:

```
public class FederationController : ApiController
{
    protected virtual string ExtractBootstrapToken()
    {
        return "Hello World";
        //return HttpContext.Current.User.BootstrapToken();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public string Get()
    {
        return "Hello Get World";
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post()
    {
        var response = this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Redirect);
        response.Headers.Add("Location", "/WebAppMVCAPI/api/federation/end?acsToken=" + ExtractBootstrapToken());
        return response;
    }
}
```

}

As you can imagine, the web application is running on my IIS Server and listening on port 80. My router is configured to forward incoming requests as needed, and when I launch my web application in visual studio I have access to the application from an internet host.

The idea is to have the Windows 8 store app get a token from ACS with a Facebook login. When I launch the win8 client, the application shows a Facebook login page. I log in with my credentials successfully. However, when I look at the webauthenticationresult.responsedata property, I only see the callback uri. Also, I don't see any log in my firewall that ACS tried to post something to my callback uri.

Comment: How have you configured your ASP.NET Web API project such that ExtractBootstrapToken() works? I added ACS using the "Identity and Access" wizard for VS2012 and then added the wif.swt nugget package but keep getting errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your replying party application return URL should be

```
http://mypublicIPaddress:80/WebAppMVCAPI/api/federation
```

not

```
http://mypublicIPaddress:80/WebAppMVCAPI/api/federation/end
```

Comment: Andrew, indeed your suggestions proved to be the solution to my problem. Thanks for your contribution.